PermitRootLogin yes not working
I have been trying to access my VPS through SSH so I can configure Wireguard client to use my VPS connection on a router. I changed PermitRootLogin to yes, which was PermitRootLogin prohibit-password.
When I tried to access via SSH, I am getting this error message:
Permission denied, publickey, password

I have restarted SSH multiple times with the same outcome.
Any advise?

I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, and the VPS provider is this company https://www.residentialvps.com/

Do you really want to SSH your server as root? That's unsecure, but if you want - make sure you did this:

Change file /etc/ssh/sshd_config on your VPS (string PermitRootLogin yes )
After that do systemctl reload ssh.service on your VPS
On your client do ssh root@YOUR_VPS_SERVER

P.S. Your root user must have a password on your VPS.
If you did all of that and problem still there you can try rm .ssh/known_hosts on your client and make another try to connect your server.

I am trying to configure wireguard client through the VPS so I can use the VPS server on my router with wireguard client, and based on my understanding the only way to do that is by accessing through SSH and install the wireguard client and export the configuration to the router once done. I setup permitrootlogin yes, and I reload the ssh service., but I have not try the rm .ssh/known_hosts yet.

I tried rm .ssh/known_hosts and I got the error message No such a file or directory. I think I am missing something, I am new to SSH and I am learning, so I am probably missing something and that's preventing my SSH login access.

I tried to login by adding the RSA SSH key to my VPS settings, so it will authenticate using the SSH key, and I am still getting the same error message, Permission denied (publickey,password)
